# GCP Dataflow not getting step logs in UI.Using python SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

[Dataflow working pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuOUa.png)

Dataflow pipeline is running fine.But cannot see the logs for each step and element added & estimated size.Using python sdk for apache beam on GCP.
Need to find out time taken at each step of pipeline that is 
1.PubSub to Bigquery
2.Pubsub to datastore
Please let me know what needs to be done to get Time metrics for each step.

Comment: What version of Beam are you using?

Comment: apache-beam 2.6.0

Comment: This may be because Python Streaming support on Dataflow is still on Beta, but let me check w the engineering team.

Comment: hey @Pablo is there any other technique to measure time taken at each step and total time taken.

Comment: @Pablo logs are still not visible, any update on this?